# splitting a text document resulting in weird strings

Tags: vb.net, split

So I have a bit of code which is effectively trying to get the text from a .txt file named users.txt, and splitting the different values every "|" symbol so that it can be read into an array.

The text file looks a little like this with the first line being what the format is:

```
MachineName|UserName|Password|  
FOXYCOMPUTER|Harry|itsasecret|
```

My aim is to load the different strings into an array so it would look something like this when displayed in the val variables:

val0: MachineName
val1: UserName
val2: Password
val3: FOXYCOMPUTER
val4: Harry
val5: itsasecret

The group of "dim val0 As String"s have been written just to test the results. Instead of what I expected above, I get:

val0: "System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, Text: MachineName"
val1: "UserName"
val2: "Password"
val3: "" & vbLf & "FOXYCOMPU..."
val4: Error Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
val5:

This isn't all of my code but it is hopefully all that is relevant to the errors.

```
         Dim filetext As New RichTextBox
         Dim directory As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
         Dim filePath As String = directory & "\users.txt"
         Dim textvaluesArr() As String

         filetext.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath)

        'split all text into array of each values
        textvaluesArr = filetext.ToString.Split(New [Char]() {CChar("|")})  '***I've been experimenting with this line, but can't find anything that will work 100% for me

        Dim val0 As String = textvaluesArr(0)
        Dim val1 As String = textvaluesArr(1)
        Dim val2 As String = textvaluesArr(2)
        Dim val3 As String = textvaluesArr(3)
        Dim val4 As String = textvaluesArr(4)
        Dim val5 As String = textvaluesArr(5)
```

Note: If I haven't been able to explain this well enough, I can create a google drive link to my project for a brave soul to venture inwards. Or you can just ask for more bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
textvaluesArr = filetext.ToString.Split(New [Char]() {CChar("|")})
```

the is getting a string representation of the RichTextBox control and its contents.

What you want is the `Text` property which is the contents of the control as follows:

```
textvaluesArr = filetext.Text.Split(New [Char]() {CChar("|")})
```

Comment: Wow. Not only was that extremely fast but it also fixed my problem in under a word. Disappointed I didn't think of it before.Thanks for the speedy and helpful response, I will mark your answer as accepted once the 10 minute timer is over :)